# Birthyear and Age check

Tags: r

So I want to check if the age and the birthyear are matching.
What is the easiest way to do that?

I think I can just add these two together and check if it is 2021.

But how would I just exlude these rows that don't match?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (preferably using `dput`) and thus we can provide a concrete answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a little function that takes the date of birth as input and returns the actual age in years as an output:

```
get_age <- function(DOB) {
  floor(lubridate::interval(DOB, lubridate::now())/lubridate::years(1))
}
```

For example, suppose you had a data frame of DOB and ages:

```r
df <- data.frame(DOB = as.Date(c("1984-07-01", "1970-09-22", 
                                 "2015-09-11", "1999-05-03")),
                 age = c(37, 51, 16, 22))

df
#>          DOB age
#> 1 1984-07-01  37
#> 2 1970-09-22  51
#> 3 2015-09-11  16
#> 4 1999-05-03  22
```

Now you want to see if the recorded ages match the actual age as calculated by the date of birth. We can add a column giving the calculated age like this:

```r
df$real_age <- get_age(df$DOB)

df
#>          DOB age real_age
#> 1 1984-07-01  37       37
#> 2 1970-09-22  51       51
#> 3 2015-09-11  16        6
#> 4 1999-05-03  22       22
```

Finally, we can filter the data frame so that we only keep the rows with the correct age.

```
df[df$age == df$real_age,]
#>          DOB age real_age
#> 1 1984-07-01  37       37
#> 2 1970-09-22  51       51
#> 4 1999-05-03  22       22
```

Comment: Sounds great, but it doesn't work for me. I only have the birthyear not the exact year and date. And it is coded as factor. So don't know..

Comment: @nero7 that's why we normally ask for a reproducible example of your data. Otherwise, we need to assume the exact format of what you have. You could convert the birth year to a number using `as.numeric(as.character(birth_year))`. The age plus the birth year should add up to 2021 or to 2020, depending on when their birthday is.